# Compile and execute an existing C# with Mono under Linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I'm trying since two weeks an existing C# project (using .NET3.5) and created unter VS 2008 to transfer it on Linux.
The program needs to work on Linux, because my university just have a Linux cluster, where I can solve my problem with a big data base.
First, I can compile my project with mono without any error. But if I want to run it with mono program.exe I get the error:

> " /home/lib/optek> mono Optek.exe  Missing method
>   System.Type::op_Inequality(Type,Type) in assembly
>   /usr/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll, referenced in assembly
>   /rwthfs/rz/cluster/home/lib/optek/System.Configuration.dll Method not
>   found: 'System.Type.op_Inequality' "

I also tried to run it with `mono --runtime=v4.0 program.exe`

> " /home/lib/optek> mono --runtime=v4.0 Optek.exe  Missing method
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal::SizeOf<[1]>(!!0) in assembly
>   /usr/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll, referenced in assembly
>   /rwthfs/rz/cluster/home/lib/optek/System.Windows.Forms.dll An
>   exception was thrown by the type initializer for
>   System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext"

The second error is at the part where the GUI should be opened, so I guess there is a problem with the `System.Windows.Forms.dll` which I used. All other libaraies I used i found at the cluster under the mono lib folder. But I don't found there no System.Windows.Forms.dll. So now I use (the windows System.Windows.Forms.dll from Monodevelop). This windows monodevlop System.Windows.Forms.dll is tested by a small a hello world program with a GUI and it works there.

Have anyone a Linux version of System.Windows.Forms.dll with I can try to use?
I also tried to compile with different commands (`mcs`, `gmcs`, `dmcs`). Are these commands are linking to special mono folders, so that the compiler use other .dll than I will use?

That does specifically to the `mscorlib.dll`?

How can you help me with other advices to my problem? If you have any other questions to my problem , please ask ;-)
Thanks

Comment: Hey. Have you, by any change, figured out what was the issue?
I am running into someting very similar.

Comment: Try compiling your app with the `-pkg:dotnet` flag so that it imports the WinForms libraries.